# Why is it necessary to call willMove(toParent: nil) to remove a child view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

Apple docs say:

> If you are implementing your own container view controller, it must
> call the willMove(toParent:) method of the child view controller
> before calling the removeFromParent() method, passing in a parent
> value of nil.

and examples online show:

> ```
> // this is to notify the the child that it's about to be removed
> viewController.willMove(toParent: nil)
> // this is to remove the child's view from its superview
> viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
> // this is to remove the child vc from its parent vc
> viewController.removeFromParent()
> ```

My question is, why would it be necessary to call `.willMove(toParent: nil)` BEFORE calling `removeFromParent()`? It seems like removeFromParent should be sufficient.. I'm wondering if anyone knows what exactly `.willMove(toParent: nil)` is doing that isn't handled in `removeFromParent()`?

Answer (score 0):

See the list of steps shown in the [Creating a custom container view controller](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/creating_a_custom_container_view_controller) documentation:

> **Remove a child view controller from your content**
> To remove a child view controller from your container, perform the following steps in order:
>
> 1. Call the child’s willMove(toParent:) method with the value nil.
> 2. Deactivate or remove any constraints for the child’s root view.
> 3. Call removeFromSuperview() on the child’s root view to remove it from the view hierarchy.
> 4. Call the child’s removeFromParent() method to finalize the end of the container-child relationship.

> Breaking a container-child relationship tells UIKit that your container view controller is no longer displaying the child’s content. You can still maintain other references to the child view controller. For example, UINavigationController manages a stack of child view controllers, but it maintains a container-child relationship with only one or two of those children at any given time.

As shown, you need to call `willMove(toParent:)` to give the child view controller a chance to do its own preparation (if any). This needs to be done before the custom container moves onto step 2.

If `willMove(toParent:)` was folded into the call to `removeFromParent()` (step 4), then the child view controller wouldn't be able to handle the removal until steps 2 and 3 were already completed by the custom container. That could be far too late.

Comment: What sort of preparation does it need to do? And you mention that if it was folded into removeFromParent() that it could be far too late. Far too late for what?

Comment: It most cases there is no preparation needed. But if your app has a specific need to do something, then the opportunity exists (in `willMove(toParent:)`. That possible preparation is the "what" for the "far too late". There are plenty of APIs that have a "will" and "did" variant. It's just a pattern with the most flexibility just incase your code needs to do something before and/or after a change.